# Issue using HAVING-Clause: Invalid expression in the select list (not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause)

Tags: sql, group-by, firebird, having-clause

Using SQL Firebird. My query return the title error and i dont know how solve it...

```sql
SELECT M.brasmed_cod_medicamento BRAMEDCODIGO,  
                                  M.brasmed_medicamento BRAMEDDESCRICAO,  
                                  NULL BRAMEDFLAG,
                                  'M' BRAMEDTIPO,
                                  NULL SELECAO,
                                  COALESCE((SELECT FIRST(1)'S'
                                   FROM TABELA_BRASINDICE_MED_RH RH  
                                       WHERE RH.brasmed_edicao = M.brasmed_edicao  
                                       AND RH.brasmed_cod_medicamento = M.brasmed_cod_medicamento  
                                       AND RH.brasmed_cod_lab = M.brasmed_cod_lab  
                                       AND RH.brasmed_cod_apresentacao = M.brasmed_cod_apresentacao),'N') RESTRITO,
                                  '0' NOVA_ORDEM,
                                  'N' PARENTAL,
                                  M.brasmed_tuss TUSS 
                           FROM TABELA_BRASINDICE_MEDICAMENTOS M  
                               WHERE M.brasmed_edicao = 973
                               GROUP BY M.brasmed_cod_medicamento,
                                        M.brasmed_medicamento
                               HAVING COUNT (*) > 1
```

In resume, i need to found one or more rows containing duplicate.

Comment: Column `M.brasmed_tuss` is in your SELECT list, however it is not being aggregated, nor is it in your `GROUP BY`. Either aggregate with a function or add it to your `GROUP BY`. I have a suspicion you may need to add `RESTRITO` to your `GROUP BY` as well.

Comment: brasmed_tuss is in select but not in group by clause